# getAttribute() Помогите разобараться

Tags: java, selenium

Не понимаю как работает код:
driver.findElement(By.id(control.getAttribute("id") + "Error"))

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Плохо знаком с селениумом, но раскидаю на составные:

Например, есть html код:

```html
<body>
    <button id="control">Кнопка</button>
    <div id="controlError">Ошибка</div>
</body>
```

получили кнопку `<button id="control">Кнопка</button>` по её типу (в коде у вас этого нет, но это важно)

```
control = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button"))
```

получили идентификатор этой кнопки как простую строку

```
control.getAttribute("id") // => "control"
```

конкретно тут мы задаем поиск элемента `<div id="controlError">Ошибка</div>`

```
By.id(control.getAttribute("id") + "Error")
```

т.к. это получается так: `By.id("control" + "Error")`

И получаем элемент:

```
driver.findElement(...)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!